# Filter out an array with null values, underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this array:

```
[null, {name:'John'}, null, {name:'Jane'}]
```

I want to remove the null values. Is there an easy way to do this with underscore?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If the array contains either nulls or objects then you could use [**compact**](http://underscorejs.org/#compact):

```
var everythingButTheNulls = _.compact(list);
```

NB compact removes all falsy values so if the array could contain zeros, false etc then they would also be removed.

Could also use [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) with the [**isNull**](http://underscorejs.org/#isNull) predicate:

```
var everythingButTheNulls = _.reject(array, _.isNull);
```

Comment: if your lodash version supports _.isNil... that would  filter null, nan, undefined. `var everythingButTheNulls = _.reject(array, _.isNil);`

Answer (score 21):

Try using `_.without(array, *values)` it will remove all the values that you don't need. In your case *values == null

http://underscorejs.org/#without

Comment: to remove nulls, I'd to without(array, undefined)

Answer (score 5):

This will work for you

**Filter**

```
_.filter(arr,function (value) {
    return value!==null;
})
```

**Reject**

```
_.reject(arr,function (value) {
    return value===null;
})
```

Comment: _.reject(arr, _.isNull) is arguably cleaner. Or just _.without(arr, null)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use [compact](https://underscorejs.org/#compact), but the default behaviour of the [filter](https://underscorejs.org/#filter) function when you don't include a specific truth test function is to remove *falsy* values

For example:

```
_.filter([null, {name:'John'}, null, {name:'Jane'}])
```

returns a object array without the nulls:

```
[{name:'John'}, {name:'Jane'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

From underscore documentation

```
without_.without(array, *values) 
Returns a copy of the array with all instances of the values removed.
```

So just use this method

```
var a = [null, {name:'John'}, null, {name:'Jane'}]
a = _.without(a, null);
```